# Creating ViewControllers using JSON or XML file

Tags: ios, json, swift

I need to create ViewControllers using JSON or XML file, because my app has many views and i am searching methods for do this automatically.

Its possible create UIViewControllers using JSON or XML with the all components included?

I search in the Google but i dont found good options about this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anything is possible.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation and **specific** programming question.

Comment: Many things are possible.  Some [things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) are not possible.  :)

Answer (score 0):

UIKit does not have any functionality for instantiating UI from JSON.

UIKit does support instantiating UI from XML.  That's called nibs, xibs, and storyboards.  Those files are XML.  You can generate them by hand, or you can use Interface Builder in Xcode to generate them graphically.

I don't recommend trying to create them by hand, the XML format is complex, hard to read, and hard to get right.  And I'm not sure it's documented completely anywhere.

You could build your own parser to read JSON or XML and instantiate the appropriate UI.  Depending on your needs I estimate it would take between two weeks and two months to complete.